# Is there a way to extend the Vocabulary size of pre-trained Embeddings (re-train word Embeddings on custom dataset on top of existing)?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, nlp, gensim, word-embedding

**TL;DR: Is there a way in `Gensim` to use the existing Embedding and extend it's vocab + learning by training it again on your custom data set?**

One can simply train their own Embedding in `Gensim` as:

```
from gensim.models import FastText # or any other model
corpus = your_custom_text_corpus

model = FastText(vector_size=4, window=3, min_count=1)  # instantiate
model.build_vocab(corpus)
model.train(corpus, total_examples=len(common_texts), epochs=10)
```

Secondly, you can load the Embeddings in `Keras / Tensorflow / PyTorch` and set the `trainable = True` as:
`layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embed_dim, weights=[embedding_matrix], trainable = True)` which might help you to update your Embedding context faster and maybe more usable.

Thirdly, you can [use Retrofitting to extend the existing knowledge](https://github.com/mfaruqui/retrofitting) but you can't extend the vocab in that one.

I have a labelled training data of `SCIENCE / PCMB / STEM)` for over 100000 instances for classification task. **BUT I have over 1.5 Million unlabelled data** which can help me train my corpus from scratch to make new `Glove / Word2Vec` from scratch.

What I want to know to is:

**Is there a way to use the existing trained Embedding and then using that as a base, add some vocab to it**? So that when I train my data of 100000 instances, it'll be relatively easy and it'll be based on top of the Old Learning too, but a bit shifted my dataset?

[A *Kind Of idea* is  given here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/33792/how-to-retrain-glove-vectors-on-top-of-my-own-data). Can someone confirm if it can be used?